# What does it means: Warning from XXX: apparmor_parser: File 'XXX' missing feature abi, falling back to default policy feature abi

Tags: upgrade, apparmor

After a dist upgrade, I get a lot of warnings like this one:

> Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient (/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient line 4): apparmor_parser: File '/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient' missing feature abi, falling back to default policy feature abi

1. what does it means? Google does not help, or I was not able to search it well
2. is it a problem?
3. if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and what kernel? Please paste the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` in your question above.

Comment: [This](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/AppArmorpolicyfeaturesabi) seems like it might be relevant - in particular [What if policy is missing an abi rule](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/AppArmorpolicyfeaturesabi)

Comment: @steeldriver So if I understood well, it seems that simply the policies are not updated to Apparmor 3. I suppose I can fix nothing. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It's probably worth a bug report, please consider filing one against `isc-dhcp-client`.

Answer (score 0):

Per [steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462729/what-does-it-means-warning-from-xxx-apparmor-parser-file-xxx-missing-featur?noredirect=1#comment2560787_1462729), this means that the file is an AppArmor policy and it's not up to date to AppArmor v3, so AppArmor falls back to the v2 policy.

Source: https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/AppArmorpolicyfeaturesabi#what-if-policy-is-missing-an-abi-rule

Answer (score 0):

It's just a poorly worded warning message. The way I interpret [the official documentation](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/AppArmorpolicyfeaturesabi#what-if-policy-is-missing-an-abi-rule) is that the actual intent of this message is

`Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient line 4: apparmor_parser: missing AppArmor ABI version declaration, defaulting to ABI version 2. This is probably okay if this was policy originally written for an older version of AppArmor.`

If I had been designing this system, I would have simply defined that missing version declaration always means version 2 and never ever emit this warning.